# Rails 3: What happens after a form button is pressed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

When I press the form button in `edit.html.erb` view, Rails goes to the "update" action.

Is this a convention ?

How can I control the target action when the form is submitted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a url for the form. See here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

```
form_for :post, :url => { :action => "custom_action" } do |f|
```

Comment: That isn't the API for Rails 3, which is what the asker is using.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to use `:url => {:action => "custom_action"}` with `form_tag` ? I could only make it work with string url like this: `form_tag "/jobs/custom_method"` ?

Comment: @misha..you can use like this `form_tag :action => "custom_action"`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the convention is for the update action to handle *updating* an object, hence its name. The conventions are that way for a reason: they're the best way of doing it, and shouldn't be changed unless you have a good reason.

I highly recommend you take a look at the [Rails Forms Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) and possibly the API documentation for [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) and [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag).